# BootstrapValidator feedbackIcons not placed in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrapvalidator

I am using BootStrapValidator in my web app and for some reason unknown to myself the feedbackIcons are not being placed in the input fields and are being placed below the input fields, and from what I see in other examples that the feedbackIcons should be placed inside the input fields and because the feedbackIcons are placed below it is throwing my layout off

Here is the picture of what it currently looks like
[image: feedbackIcons are not where they should be]

Here is an example of how the feedbackIcons are to be displayed
[image: How the feedbackIcons should be layed out]

Here is my markup

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
        .max-size {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
            color: white;
            background-color: #347AB6;
        }

        .panel-heading {
            border-top-left-radius: 0px;
            border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        }

        .panel {
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
    </style>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#CustomerData" data-toggle="tab">Customer Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubDivisionAssignment" data-toggle="tab">SubDivision Assignment</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="CustomerData">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel panel-heading"><strong>Add/Edit Customer</strong></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <fieldset class="Myfieldset">
                                <legend class="Mylegend"><h4><b>Address</b></h4></legend>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerFirstName" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerFirstName"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerFirstName" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="firstname" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerLastName" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerLastName"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerLastName" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="lastname" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerAddress1">Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerAddress1" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="address" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="CustomertxtAddress2" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerAddress2">Address2</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerAddress2" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">                                    
                                    <label for="txtCustomerCity" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerCity">City</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerCity" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="txtCustomerCounty" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerCounty">County</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerCounty" type="text" class="form-control" name="County" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="acState" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerState"><b>State</b></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <select id="acState" class="form-control" name="state"></select>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="txtCustomerZip" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerZip">Zip/Postal</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerZip" type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerYearBuilt" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerYearBuilt">Year Built</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerYearBuilt" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="yearbuilt" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <fieldset class="Myfieldset">
                                <legend class="Mylegend"><h4><b>Contact</b></h4></legend>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerContact" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerContact">Contact</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerContact" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="customercontact" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerEmail" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationModeratorEmail"><b>Email</b></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerEmail" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtPhone" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerPhone">Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtPhone" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="phone" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerFax" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerFax">Fax</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerFax" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerMobile" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerMobile">Mobile</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerMobile" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCustomerOther" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCustomerOther">Other</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="txtCustomerOther" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="SubDivisionAssignment">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel panel-heading"><strong>Add/Edit SubDivision Assignment</strong></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Off
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Customjs/Customer/CustomerEditorJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my BootstrapValidator code

```
function ValidateCustomer(){
    var validator = $("#CustomerData").bootstrapValidator({
        excluded: ':disabled',
        container: 'tooltip',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok",
            invalid: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove",
            validating: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
        },
        fields: {
            firstname: {
                message: "First Name is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add First Name"
                    }
                }
            },
            lastname: {
                message: "Last Name is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add Last Name"
                    }
                }
            },
            address: {
                message: "Address is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add Address"
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                message: "City is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add City"
                    }
                }
            },
            zip: {
                message: "ZipCode is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add ZipCode"
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                message: "City is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add City"
                    }
                }
            },
            state: {
                message: "State is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add State"
                    }
                }
            },
            yearbuilt: {
                message: "Year Built is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add Year Built"
                    }
                }
            },
            phone: {
                message: "Phone is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add Phone"
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                message: "Email address is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please provide Email address"
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: "Email address was invalid"
                    }
                }
            },
            customercontact: {
                message: "Contact name is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please add Contact name"
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    });
}
```

Comment: Where you are calling this `ValidateCustomer` method??

Comment: On a button click called btnSave